# FOSUserBundle and EasyAdmin - too few arguments when add new Group

Tags: fosuserbundle, symfony4

I haved installed a fosuerbundle, everything is ok, but not with groups. I use Symfony4.1 and when i try add new group through easyadmin i got error like that:

Too few arguments to function FOS\UserBundle\Model\Group::__construct(), 0 passed in /home/.../app/vendor/easycorp/easyadmin-bundle/src/Controller/AdminController.php on line 441 and at least 1 expected

Any idea what`s wrong that can be ?

UPDATE

StackTrace:

```
 at vendor/friendsofsymfony/user-bundle/Model/Group.php:40
  at FOS\UserBundle\Model\Group->__construct()
     (vendor/easycorp/easyadmin-bundle/src/Controller/AdminController.php:441)
  at EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Controller\AdminController->createNewEntity()
  at call_user_func_array(array(object(AdminController), 'createNewEntity'), array())
     (vendor/easycorp/easyadmin-bundle/src/Controller/AdminController.php:790)
  at EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Controller\AdminController->executeDynamicMethod('createNew&lt;EntityName&gt;Entity')
     (vendor/easycorp/easyadmin-bundle/src/Controller/AdminController.php:278)
  at EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Controller\AdminController->newAction()
  at call_user_func_array(array(object(AdminController), 'newAction'), array())
     (vendor/easycorp/easyadmin-bundle/src/Controller/AdminController.php:790)
  at EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Controller\AdminController->executeDynamicMethod('new&lt;EntityName&gt;Action')
     (vendor/easycorp/easyadmin-bundle/src/Controller/AdminController.php:80)
  at EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Controller\AdminController->indexAction(object(Request))
     (vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php:149)
  at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(object(Request), 1)
     (vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php:66)
  at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(object(Request), 1, true)
     (vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Kernel.php:188)
  at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->handle(object(Request))
     (public/index.php:37)
```